# getElementsByTagName issue

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname, dom-traversal

1. I have page with many doubleclick scripts
2. I have js code inserted    at the body top (via s.src=('parts_async_dev.js')):

   ```
   var innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML.toString();
   var regexp = /ad.doubleclick.net/gm;
   var matches = innerHTML.match(regexp);
   alert('found ' + matches.length + ' tags by regexp ' + regexp);
   console.log( innerHTML);
   ```

`alert` says that matches returns only 2 of `ad.doubleclick.net` tags.
I thought first that code can not access whole body  if not placed at the body very bottom.
But it finds 2 tags inside div "interstitial_wrapper" which comes after my code.

So my questions are:

- why is it so
- How to access whole body form body start ( i may not use body 'onload' event. it is required to use script asap)

Please take a look at http://wap7.ru/folio/bannerstat/partners/doubleclick2.html
and see view source, because it is too large to include here.

Comment: I get 28 when I visit that page.

Comment: Make sure the DOM is loaded before you search for elements.

Comment: @Stefan - i may not use body onload event

Comment: @Linus G Thiel - what browser do you use?

Comment: Chromium. I get 2 in Firefox. But yeah, I don't think you can get around waiting for body onload. That's kind of what it's there for...

Comment: is not it weird that i can not access whole body code from itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to bind to the onload event. Just bind to the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Since you've already included jQuery in your page, this can esily be done using [`.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
    /* If you want to use a RegExp, use the following:
    var regexp = /ad\.doubleclick\.net/gi; // Note: escaped dot
    var matches = innerHTML.match(regexp);
    matches = matches ? matches.length : 0; // matches can be `null`
    */

    // This is more effective:
    var matches = innerHTML.split('ad.doubleclick.net').length - 1;
    alert('Found ' + matches + ' tags.');
    console.log( innerHTML );
});
```

Comment: Thanks!

i cant rely on jquery since it is not my page.



i do   **window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', func, false);**




see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Other_events for details

Comment: @Lev Before doing so, check whether the page has already fired the `DOMContentLoaded` event, via [`document.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.readyState).

Comment: since my code is in very top i am not sure if it is possible  to have ready state loaded.

Comment: any way i use such snippet. is it correct?

`function addDOMContentLoadedEvent(func) {

   // debug(document.readyState);

    if (document.readyState == 'interactive' || document.readyState == 'complete' ){

        func();

    }else{
        if (window.addEventListener) {
                window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', func, false);
            }
       
    }


}`

Comment: @Lev Kind of (you're ignoring IE). Have a look at this Stack Overflow Q&A for a cross-browser implementation: [$(document).ready() source](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3430455/938089?document-ready-source).